# Performing a query results in a "no such column" exception

Tags: android, sqlite

My query is

```
 dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDB("OmniaDB",new String[]{"imsi","type","msg","length","dt_gen","dt_send"},"type"+"="+"call"+"AND"+"dt_send"+"="+"null",null,null,null,"dt_gen");
```

Thrown exception is

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: callANDdt_send: , while compiling: SELECT imsi, type, msg, length, dt_gen, dt_send FROM OmniaDB WHERE type=callANDdt_send=null ORDER BY dt_gen
```

Comment: You've asked 9 questions and haven't voted on or accepted on any of them.

Comment: Please see [How does accepting answers work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you don't know how to accept answers (or why).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a ton of spaces in `"type"+"="+"call"+"AND"+"dt_send"+"="+"null"`, should be `"type='call' AND dt_send=null"`. Why are you even using concatenation when it should be a giant string? Anyway, there might be something else wrong after you fix that, though, since I have no clue what your data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

```
"type"+"="+"call"+"AND"+"dt_send"+"="+"null"
```

None of this makes sense. Getting rid of the unnecessary concatenations leaves

```
"type = call AND dt_send = null"
```

which is invalid SQL. You're not quoting properly for the string `call`, and you can't compare `NULL` for equality with anything (including `NULL`).

This is more likely what you should be using:

```
"type = 'call' AND dt_send IS NULL"
```

There are probably other problems with the mess you posted, but this should solve at least one of them. (For instance, `type` may be a reserved word in SQLite; I'm not sure.)